# Extract month and year from a POSIXct column to create a new column

Tags: r, posixct

I have the data below:

```
pr5915<-structure(list(activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
"Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
"BBH-1&2", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "TCE Cleaning", "SOLO Oil", 
"Tempering", "TCE Cleaning", "Tempering", "BBH-1&2", "BBH-1&2", 
"TCE Cleaning", "Tempering"), timestamp = structure(c(-62042010952, 
-62010323872, -61884118792, -61821087232, -61821025132, -61789534972, 
-61789520332, -61789494952, -61757940232, -61757925652, -61757895952, 
-61694827552, -61694808292, -61663337152, -61663307452), tzone = "Europe/Istanbul", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("eventlog", "log", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", activity_instance_id = "action", lifecycle_id = "lifecycle", resource_id = "resource", timestamp = "timestamp")
```

[image]

and I want to create 1 new column named `Date` which will extract the month and the Year from the `timestamp` column. For example if month is `12` and year `20` then the new column will have `"December-20"`.

***formated dataset

```
pr5915<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4120721", "WC4120667", "WC4120689"
), lifecycle = c(110, 110, 110), action = c("WC4120721-CN354877", 
"WC4120667-CN354878", "WC4120689-CN356752"), activity = c("Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", 
"Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)", "Forged Wire, Medium (Sport)"), 
    resource = c("3419", "3216", "3409"), timestamp = structure(c(1606964400, 
    1607115480, 1607435760), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does the trick using functions form `tidyverse` and `lubridate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

pr5915 %>% 
 mutate(
  timestamp = ymd_hms(
    as_datetime(
     as.character(timestamp), format = "00%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
    ),
  Date = paste0(
   month(timestamp, label = T, abbr = F), 
   "-", 
   substr(year(timestamp), 3 , 4)
  )
)
```

**Outcome**

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   activity                    timestamp           Date       
   <chr>                       <dttm>              <chr>      
 1 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 2020-12-03 06:00:00 December-20
 2 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 2020-12-04 23:58:00 December-20
 3 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 2020-12-08 16:56:00 December-20
 4 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 2020-12-10 05:42:00 December-20
 5 BBH-1&2                     2020-12-10 22:57:00 December-20
 6 Forged Wire, Medium (Sport) 2020-12-11 10:13:00 December-20
 7 TCE Cleaning                2020-12-11 14:17:00 December-20
 8 SOLO Oil                    2020-12-11 21:20:00 December-20
 ...
```

For the formatted dataset you need to alter the `format` argument to match the `dttm` format: `format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: thank you could you adapt the solution to the formated dataset of my edit?